# How to style the last post on the front page different than the others?

Tags: posts, css

I would like the last post of the front page to be styled differently than the rest, how could I achive this?

This is the index.php

```
<?php
get_header();
?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php else : ?>
<article id="post-0" class="post no-results not-found">
<section>
<h3><a href="#">Sorry!</a></h3>
<p>Hier gibt es nichts zu sehen. </p>
<section>
</article><!-- #post-0 -->

<?php endif; ?>
<div id='postNavi'>
    <div class='older'><?php next_posts_link('Ältere Beiträge &raquo;');?></div>
    <div class='newer'><?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Neuere Beiträge');?></div>
</div>

<?php
get_footer();
?>
```

and the two formats I use:

content-aside.php

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class();?> >


<h1><?php if(is_single()) {?>
<?php the_title();?>
<?php } else { ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a>
<?php }?>
</h1>
<div class='postMeta2'>
<?php the_category(' | ') ?>
</div>

<section class='multi-column'>
<?php
    if ( is_home() ) {
        the_excerpt();
    } else {
        the_content('Weiterlesen');
    }
?>
 </section></article>
```

and content-quote.php

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class();?> >

    <h1>
        <?php if(is_single()) {?>
        <?php the_title();?>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a>
        <?php }?>
    </h1>

    <div class='postMeta2'>
     <?php the_category(' | ') ?>
    </div>

    <section>
        <blockquote>
        <?php
            the_content('read the rest');
        ?>
        </blockquote>
    </section>

</article>
```

Answer (score 2):

To accomplish this, you will need to know which is the last post on the page. There are a couple ways to achieve this, but I think the easiest way is to use pure php, the function [`end()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php). You are going to use this to get the last post in the loop.

Once you have the last post in the loop, you can simply just compare the last post's ID with the current post ID, and if they match, you can apply your custom styling

In your `content-*.php`, you can try the following

```
$last_post = end($wp_query->posts);
if ($last_post->ID == $post->ID) {

    //Apply your styling for the last post

}
```